# Set and retrieve Spinner data from shared-preferences

Tags: android, spinner, sharedpreferences

I have 3 Spinners, The Main one to chose the category and 2 other From and To.

What I need is to save the last users choice and retrieve it when the users open the App for next time.

Here is my code:

```
        //Here is my spinner
    UnitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.UnitSpinner);
    UnitSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    UnitSpinner.setAdapter(new UnitArray(UnitConverter.this, R.layout.row,
            (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array))));

    //Here is my spinners From and to
    SpinnerFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFrom);
    SpinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    SpinnerTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTo);
    SpinnerTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //MY array adapter
    UnitArrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    UnitArrayadapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpinnerFrom.setAdapter(UnitArrayadapter);
    SpinnerTo.setAdapter(UnitArrayadapter);
    UnitArrayadapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

I know that the best way to save it is in the onPause and to retrieve it from the onCreate.

Note: I am using a customized spinner (row.xml layout) for my Main spinner.

Thanks for any help in Advance.

UPDATE: here is how I tried to do it:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    int selectedPosition = UnitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);

    editor.commit();
```

I don't know if its working but The point is I don't know how to retrieve it from Sharedprefereces in my onCreate!

UPDATE 2:

```
    private Spinner UnitSpinner;
private TextView inputValue;
private Spinner SpinnerFrom;
private Spinner SpinnerTo;
private Button ButtonConvert;
private TextView ResultView;
ArrayAdapter<String> UnitArray;
ArrayAdapter<String> UnitArrayadapter;
private Strategy currentStrategy;
private String unitfrom;
private String unitto;
private static UnitConverter instance;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Adapter1;
/** SharedPreferences */
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String inputValueNamber = "InputYourNumber";
public static final String Result = "TheResultIs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@SuppressLint({ "ShowToast", "NewApi" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

    inputValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditTextValue);

    /** SharedPreferences */
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(inputValueNamber)) {
        inputValue.setText(sharedpreferences
                .getString(inputValueNamber, ""));
    }

    /** SharedPreferences for Spinner */
    int selectedPosition = sharedpreferences.getInt("spinnerSelection", 0);
    /** End */

    /** End of SharedPreferences */

    Button buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonAbout);
    b1.setOnClickListener(mb1);

    /** Hide Auto Keyboard */
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    /** Hide Auto Keyboard End here */

    UnitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.UnitSpinner);
    UnitSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    UnitSpinner.setAdapter(new UnitArray(UnitConverter.this, R.layout.row,
            (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array))));

    SpinnerFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFrom);
    SpinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    SpinnerTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTo);
    SpinnerTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    UnitArrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    UnitArrayadapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpinnerFrom.setAdapter(UnitArrayadapter);
    SpinnerTo.setAdapter(UnitArrayadapter);
    UnitArrayadapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    ResultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewResult);
    ResultView.setClickable(false);
    ButtonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    ButtonConvert.setOnClickListener(this);

    /** initialization */
    currentStrategy = new Temperature();
    instance = this;
}

private void setRetainInstance(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/** For Icons */
public class UnitArray extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public UnitArray(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.SelectUnits);
        label.setText(getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array)[position]);

        TextView sub = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        sub.setText(getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.my_string_array_sub)[position]);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

        return row;
    }
}

public static UnitConverter getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    if (v.getParent() == UnitSpinner) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            setStrategy(new Temperature());
            break;

        case 1:
            setStrategy(new Weight());
            break;

        case 2:
            setStrategy(new Length());
            break;

        case 3:
            setStrategy(new Power());
            break;

        case 4:
            setStrategy(new Energy());
            break;

        case 5:
            setStrategy(new Velocity());
            break;

        case 6:
            setStrategy(new Area());
            break;

        case 7:
            setStrategy(new Volume());
            break;
        }

        fillFromToSpinner(position);

        SpinnerFrom.setSelection(0);
        SpinnerTo.setSelection(0);

        unitfrom = (String) (SpinnerFrom.getItemAtPosition(0).toString());
        unitto = (String) (SpinnerTo.getItemAtPosition(0).toString());

        /** reset the result */
        ResultView.setText("");

    } else if (v.getParent() == SpinnerFrom) {
        unitfrom = (String) (SpinnerFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    else if (v.getParent() == SpinnerTo) {
        unitto = (String) (SpinnerTo.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
}

private void fillFromToSpinner(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fillSpinnerWithTempUnit();
        break;

    case 1:
        fillSpinnerWithWeightUnit();
        break;

    case 2:
        fillSpinnerWithLengthUnit();
        break;

    case 3:
        fillSpinnerWithPowerUnit();
        break;

    case 4:
        fillSpinnerWithenErgyUnit();
        break;

    case 5:
        fillSpinnerWithVelocityUnit();
        break;

    case 6:
        fillSpinnerWithAreaUnit();
        break;

    case 7:
        fillSpinnerWithVolumeUnit();
        break;
    }

}

private void fillSpinnerWithTempUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.temperatureunitc));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.temperatureunitf));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.temperatureunitkelvin));
    UnitArrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void fillSpinnerWithWeightUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.weightunitkg));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.weightunitgm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.weightunitlb));
    UnitArrayadapter
            .add(getResources().getString(R.string.weightunitounce));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.weightunitmg));
    UnitArrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void fillSpinnerWithLengthUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitmile));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitkm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitcm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitmm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitinch));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.lengthunitfeet));
}

private void fillSpinnerWithPowerUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.powerunitwatts));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.powerunithorseposer));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.powerunitkilowatts));
}

private void fillSpinnerWithenErgyUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.energyunitcalories));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.energyunitjoules));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.energyunitkilocalories));

}

private void fillSpinnerWithVelocityUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.velocityunitkmph));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.velocityunitmilesperh));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.velocityunitmeterpers));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.velocityunitfeetpers));
}

private void fillSpinnerWithAreaUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqkm));
    UnitArrayadapter
            .add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqmiles));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqcm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqmm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.areaunitsqyard));
}

private void fillSpinnerWithVolumeUnit() {
    UnitArrayadapter.clear();
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.volumeunitlitres));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.volumeunitmillilitres));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.volumeunitcubicm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.volumeunitcubiccm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.volumeunitcubicmm));
    UnitArrayadapter.add(getResources().getString(
            R.string.volumeunitcubicfeet));
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == ButtonConvert) {
        if (!inputValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            double in = Double.parseDouble(inputValue.getText().toString());
            double result = currentStrategy.Convert(unitfrom, unitto, in);
            ResultView.setText(String.format("%.02f", result));
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        } else {
            ResultView.setText("");
        }
    }
}

private void setStrategy(Strategy s) {

    currentStrategy = s;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    String ive = inputValue.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(inputValueNamber, ive);

    int selectedPosition = UnitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);

    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: have you made an attempt at doing it? If so, post it. If not, try it.

Comment: You could store the spinner positions as integers. Then retrieve them and set the spinners at those positions (after loading them)

Comment: I dont see a question here. Are you asking for help on saving the preferences? are you having trouble finding the correct time to retrieve the data? Please clarify your problem

Comment: please read the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data (and like you said, you would put it in `onCreate`) you would do something like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int selection = sharedpreferences.getInt("spinnerSelection",0);
```

Essentially what that does is it tries to grab whatever int is mapped to the string "spinnerSelection" and, if nothing is mapped to it, `selection` is made to 0, the second parameter in `getInt`.

Comment: its giving me "The value of the local variable selection is not used"

Comment: well then, use it. `UnitSpinner.setSelection(selection);`

Comment: nothing happen ... still no retrieve ... or maybe my onPause is wrong!!

Comment: @user2610397 one thing I would try is setting the `SharedPreferences` value every time you set a spinner selection instead of in `onPause` (so, like as soon as you go into `onItemSelected`).

Comment: do you mean like this...  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
   long id) {
  
  Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
     int selectedPosition = UnitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
     editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);
  editor.commit();

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need `UnitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();' because that int is passed as `int position`. You can just do `editor.putInt("spinnerSelection",position);`

Comment: still no retrieve ... but you helped me a lot ... thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to give you that your answer is useful but my reputation is so down :o :) ...

Comment: @user2610397 you can accept it if it helped by clicking the check next to it

Comment: it didn't helped me but it might help another people ... so I will accept it. thanks